# Magento custom options not work

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento, magento-1.9

I set the settings for Custom options and everything is visualized well. While the browser loads, the Drop Down menu it works, after it loaded the page, еverything is blocked. There is some incompatibility in the HTML code. This is the link:http://massa.bg/dostavka/deserti/sladoledi/sladoled-kukis. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add following css :-

> .post-social {
>       float: left;
>   }

and check it will work

Comment: Тhanks for the reply!
I can not find the directory from where it is rewrit  the css code.

Comment: i have answered again with new fix so add that css in your stylesheet and check it will work like charm :)